# Does admob provides rewarded video ads?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I have a banner ad and an rewardes video ad the banner is working perfectly but the rewarded video is showing only test ads even with the real ad id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for some times.

After waiting some times/hours if still having problem then you need to cross check Ad unit Id and AppId from AdMob account.

If you are able to load test ads but not live ads, it sounds like an issue with your AdMob account.

Make sure that you properly set up a payment system and/or verified your PIN? If they are not done, then live ads would not be served from your account.

I've link below, you can post your problem there.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/fBe3YL3ffpo